# Select rows where ('score'+'score_bonus')>0, but one of the values may be NULL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 2 columns in my table:

```
score DOUBLE NULL
score_bonus DOUBLE NULL
```

I have a row that has the following values:

`score` = NULL
`score_bonus` = 50

When I do the following query it doesn't return the above row:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (score+score_bonus) > 0 LIMIT 1
```

What I am doing wrong? My main suspect is the NULL value, but I guess this should have been taken in account by MySQL as zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to avoid `null` values because `5 + null = null`

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE coalesce(score,0) + coalesce(score_bonus,0) > 0 
LIMIT 1
```

or if you only have positive values you can use

```
SELECT * FROM your_table 
WHERE greatest(score,score_bonus) > 0 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add a overhead when there are many rows? The extra function call I mean.

Comment: Probably a little one. But you need to replace `null` values with `0` in calculations.